unable to view or save reports - wordpress site
I have my initial set up of civiCRM on C-panel (vs 122), civiCRM 5.80-wordpress (6.7.1) PHP vs 8.3.13 on C-panel.  When I try to create, save or veiw a report in civiCRM I am sent to a Wordpress 404 page. There have been no errors in the civi log or shown in the browser console. Access permissions appear to be correct. I have tried uninstalling, then re-sintalling wordpress and Civi. I am logged in to Wordpress as the Administrator. I have even turned off the Authentication guards (Administer>system settings)
I didnt have this problem when I installed the same wp-civiCRM on my PC.
I have run out of ideas to fix this road-block! So, any further suggestions would be much appreciated.
